# PHP/SQL - Limiting amount of results in a certain page

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I'm looking to limit the amount of results on a page to 20, but at the bottom of the page would be 1,2,3,4 etc. How would I do this? I've got this so far but don't know where to go from here:
Code:

```
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $database);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db('evocityi_stocks');

$query = "SELECT * FROM FUMUKU"; //
$result = mysql_query($query);

echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Stock Name</th>
<th>Stock Price</th>
<th>Time</th>
</tr>";


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   
echo "<tr><td>" . $row['Stock'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Price'] . "<td>" . $row['TimeD'] . "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>"; //Close the table in HTML
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: What you are referring to is called 'pagination'. Fortunately, there are many solutions for this you can quickly search for.

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding or tutorial or library finding service** You have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
<?php 
if (isset(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["page"]))) 
{
    $page  = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["page"]); 
}
else  
{ 
$page=1;
 }
$start_from = ($page-1) * 20; 
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $database);
if(! $conn )
{
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('evocityi_stocks');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM FUMUKU ORDER BY Stock ASC LIMIT $start_from, 20"; 
$result = mysql_query($query);
?> 

echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Stock Name</th>
<th>Stock Price</th>
<th>Time</th>
</tr>";


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   
echo "<tr><td>" . $row['Stock'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Price'] . "<td>" . 

$row['TimeD'] . "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>"; //Close the table in HTML 
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(Stock) FROM FUMUKU"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql); 
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result); 
$total_records = $row[0]; 
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / 20); 

for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 
            echo "<a href='yourpage.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> "; 
}; 
?>
```

Comment: downvoted, because of xss issues (plain writing of values from a database to the HTML). http://www.sitepoint.com/php-security-cross-site-scripting-attacks-xss/

Comment: thanks for the concern, i just helped the user to get his page navigation thing done. It is the users responsibility to maintain such things. He can use PDO statement its upto hum

Comment: PDO does not protect against xss. It is the answerer's responsibility not to put harmful code in an answer. That why I downvoted it.

Comment: Now corrected my mistake used htmlspecialchars to prevent xss issue. Thank you

Comment: Yes, but you've used it in the wrong place. `htmlspecialchars` is used on output, not input. on input you use `mysql_real_escape_string`. Read the linked article above. In this case you need to correct the `echo` lines.